# Getting error in Firebase one to one chat app Notifications

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have made a one to one chat app and I have implemented chat notifications but when I am sending notifications from the user app to the doctor app but my doctor app crashes as soon as I am clicking on the chat notification

This is my Java class where I am handling the notification if my app is in foreground so this class will handle notifications so now in this class I am calling firebase database and taking some data from there and passing that data as an extra data with the resulting intent but when that resulting intent directs the app to the particular chat view that database  data is not there

This is the Log of my app

```
E/MyFirebaseMessaging: From:408315985482
07-05 16:19:33.803 4399-6278/com.tech.pritz.bemoprovider D/MyFirebaseMessaging: in between Firebase and auth
07-05 16:19:33.805 4399-6278/com.tech.pritz.bemoprovider D/MyFirebaseMessaging: Message data payload: {idRe, username=komal , message=hi}
07-05 16:19:33.805 4399-6278/com.tech.pritz.bemoprovider D/MyFirebaseMessaging: app in background
07-05 16:19:33.813 4399-6278/com.tech.pritz.bemoprovider E/MyFirebaseMessaging: image not found
07-05 16:19:33.825 4399-6278/com.tech.pritz.bemoprovider D/NotificationUtil: New Message

D/MyFirebaseMessaging: Entered into the database

07-05 16:19:34.359 4399-4399/com.tech.pritz.bemoprovider D/MyFirebaseMessaging: HKNi1sezUpbwJSeEGos44FtfUw43
```

You can see here it is showing entered in the database also and it is getting that data also but when I pass it as an intent it is not found in another activity.

Crash log

---

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.lang.String
>   com.tech.pritz.bemoprovider.model.Provider.getId()' on a null object
>   reference at
>   com.tech.pritz.bemoprovider.bemo.ChatView.ini(ChatView.java:‌​350) at
>   com.tech.pritz.bemoprovider.bemo.ChatView.onCreate(ChatView.‌​java:150)

---

```
  public class MyFirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService
    {

        private  static  final String TAG=MyFirebaseMessaging.class.getSimpleName();
        private NotificationUtil notificationUtil;
        private DatabaseReference pathFirebase;
        private FirebaseAuth auth;
        private Provider mprovider;

        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
        {
            Log.e(TAG,"From:"+ remoteMessage.getFrom());
            pathFirebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            Log.d(TAG,"in between Firebase and auth");
            auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();



            if(remoteMessage ==null )
            {
                return;

            }
            //check if message contains a notification payload
            if(remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null)
            {
                String tittle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
                Log.e(TAG,"Notification Body:" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
                handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),tittle,null, mprovider);
            }
            //checks to see if message contains a data payload
            if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
               String imageUrl = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");
              //  String message =  remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
               // String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
               // String name = remoteMessage.getData().get("username");

               String message= remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
                String name= remoteMessage.getData().get("username");
                String title= "New Message";
                String iduser= remoteMessage.getData().get("iduser");
                String email=  remoteMessage.getData().get("email");
                String gcm_id=  remoteMessage.getData().get("idGCM");
                String conversation_id=remoteMessage.getData().get("conversation_id");

                Log.d(TAG,"app in background");



                pathFirebase.child("users").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .addValueEventListener(
                                new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                            Log.d(TAG,"Entered into the database");
                                            mprovider = dataSnapshot.getValue(Provider.class);
                                            UserDataHolder.getInstance().setmName(mprovider.getName());
                                            // Intent intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessaging.this, ListPatients.class);
                                            mprovider.setId(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                                            UserDataHolder.getInstance().setmUserId(mprovider.getId());
                                            // intent.putExtra("user", provider);
                                            //startActivity(intent);
                                            //finish();
                                            Log.d(TAG,mprovider.getId());
                                        }
                                    }
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                        Toast.makeText(MyFirebaseMessaging.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });


    //            Log.d(TAG,mprovider.getId());
                // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ChatView.class);
                resultIntent.putExtra("user_id", iduser);
                resultIntent.putExtra("email", email);
                resultIntent.putExtra("User_display_name",name);
                resultIntent.putExtra("user_gcm_id",gcm_id);
                resultIntent.putExtra("conversation_id",conversation_id);
               // resultIntent.putExtra("providerLocal",mprovider);


                resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                //  resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

                // check for image attachment
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl))
                {
                    Log.e(TAG,"image not found");
                    showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message,name,resultIntent,mprovider);
                }
                else
                {
                    // image is present, show notification with image
                    Log.e(TAG,"image found");
                    showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, resultIntent, imageUrl);
                }
            }

        }


        private void handleNotification(String message,String title,String name,Provider provider)
        {

            if(!NotificationUtil.isAppInBackground(getApplicationContext()))
            {
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChatView.class);
                showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message,null,resultIntent, provider);

            }
            else
            {
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChatView.class);
                showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message,null,resultIntent, mprovider);

            }
        }

        private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context applicationContext, String title, String message, Intent resultIntent, String imageUrl)
        {
            notificationUtil = new NotificationUtil(applicationContext);
            resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            notificationUtil.showNotificationMessage(title, message,null,resultIntent,imageUrl);

        }

        private void showNotificationMessage(Context applicationContext, String title, String message,String name, Intent resultIntent,Provider mprovider)
        {
           // Log.d(TAG,mprovider.getId());
            notificationUtil = new NotificationUtil(applicationContext);
            resultIntent.putExtra("providerLocal",mprovider);
            // resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            notificationUtil.showNotificationMessage(title, message,name,resultIntent);


        }

    }
```

Comment: post crash log here

Comment: it is basically giving NPE because it is not able to get data

Comment: what I am saying that it I am taking that data from database and I am passing that data with the intent but what is happening here is according to log

Comment: can you post your crash log here?

Comment: that it making the intent and passing it and after that it is making a call to the database

Comment: that it making the intent and passing it and after that it is making a call to the database

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.tech.pritz.bemoprovider.model.Provider.getId()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.tech.pritz.bemoprovider.bemo.ChatView.ini(ChatView.java:350)
                                                                             at com.tech.pritz.bemoprovider.bemo.ChatView.onCreate(ChatView.java:150)

Comment: if (extras!=null)
        {
            //user = (User) extras.get("user");
            User_fcm_id = (String) extras.get("user_gcm_id");
            User_name = extras.getString("User_display_name");
            User_id = extras.getString("user_id");
            String session = extras.getString("session");
            conversationId = extras.getString("conversation_id");
            Log.d(TAG,conversationId);
            providerLocal = (Provider)extras.get("provider");
            Log.d(TAG,providerLocal.getId());

Comment: @VikasKumar Please click the edit link under your question to add information to it. That allows you to properly format the code and error messages, making it much easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in this line :

```
UserDataHolder.getInstance().setmUserId(mprovider.getId());
```

the `mprovider` object is null